# Replacing power transistor with relay in a battery charger circuit

Tags: transistors, relay, charger

I found [**this circuit**](https://electronicsarea.com/12v-auto-turn-off-battery-charger-with-current-limiter/), which supposedly limits the charging current to 2A max. This is for acid/lead batteries.

[image]

Then, I would like to NOT use a power transistor like 2N3055, but instead use a relay as, perhaps, follows (ignore the 1A relay rating in diagram):

[image]

I couldn't simulate it with LTSpice because I don't have the relay component. I do have Electronics Workbench but it won't run the simulator with Win10. In any case, I would like to know if it should work using a low power transistor plus relay. Also, perhaps the BD135 + 2N3055, ideally using a low power transistor instead the 3055, could be simplified using a Darlington like TIP122?

UPDATE

This is from the site that has the circuit:

> How does the current limitation work? If the load current is 2 amps,
> there is a voltage of approximately 0.94 V at the terminals of the R7
> resistor. This voltage charge the C2 capacitor through the R3
> resistor. This voltage is applied between the base and the emitter of
> transistor Q1. (0.65V approximately) and activate Q1.
>
> The transistor Q1 start to conduct and remove some of the base current
> from the Q3 transistor, which in turn removes a bit of base current
> from the Q4 transistor, which determines the amount of charge current.

So why use a 15A transitor? Why not one slightly greater than 2A?

Comment: Why do you want to use a relay?

Comment: @KevinWhite where I live, we no access to such power transistors like 2N3055

Comment: Please *simulate* above original circuit with a voltage sweep for the battery from 12 V to 14.4 V, instrumenting current through the PNP as well as charge current. Rectified 15 V sine isn't anything like 15 V DC: compare.

Comment: A relay is not a suitable replacement. I'm surprised that power transistors are not available if other components are. Almost any power transistor could work even ones scavenged from old equipment. The 2n3055 in particular is over 50 years old.

Comment: @KevinWhite 2N3055 are quite scarce here, more easy to find are those used in CRT horizontal control, but the ones I see are <15A, basically 8A is all the power I can find. Ah oh...and maybe some Mosfet like IRF630 but nevertherless are 9A as well.

Comment: I already did a question about this in this site: why I need to use much powerful transistors than the current they are supposedly to  be handling in a circuit? If this one says limits at 2A, why I need a 15A transistor? Why not 5A or 9A or whatever >2A?

Comment: You don't need a 15A transistor - 2N3055 was probably chosen because they are very cheap and easily available in most parts of the world. Provided it has an adequate heat sink a much smaller device is acceptable.

Comment: @KevinWhite oh, thats a different 5 bucks, as we say here. In my former question regarding this, I didnt get a straight answer: is there a way to pick the transistor? I mean, something like circuit rate + x Amps? Or it is just empirically like "anything greater than circuit amps", including just one amp over?

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that R7 should be 0.47 ohms, not 0.47k.

With the relay as drawn, there's *nothing* limiting the current through the battery when the relay is on, not even R7.  And when it's off, there's no charging at all.

The circuit is now sensing the current through the relay coil, which doesn't tell you anything about the state of the battery.

Comment: that's what i was afraid of

Comment: it's almost impossible to do active current limiting without a power transistor, so this is maybe not a helpful approach. The nearest you can get is a series power resistor of 7R which of course limits current to 2A but gives half the voltage you want at 1A. In the end you will need power transistors to do this properly. Where do you live?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a simple and very common LM317 regulator, they're easy to configure as a battery charger.  Look in the datasheet for example circuits, or google a bit.
This one has a battery charger example on the first page!
[Texas Instruments version of the LM317](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf)